# Are template arguments like 'T' always interpreted as per-value?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following small example:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T a) { ... }
struct Bar { ... };
Bar x;
foo(x);
```

My question: Are there any cases where `foo(x)` may be interpreted as `foo(const Bar& x)` (x passed by reference), or is it always interpreted as `foo(Bar x)` (x passed by value i.e. explicit copy of x)?

In my concrete application my code relies on the fact that a copy is created (x is used in another thread and the original x goes out of scope). But I am not sure if I can assume that. I am using GCC 4.6.1.

Comment: Why not try it in an example. I think T can be anything from int to pointer, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *deduced*, it will always be passed by value. However, if you make the template arguments explicit, you can get it passed by reference:

```
foo<Bar&>(x); // will pass by reference
foo<Bar const&>(x); // will pass by reference to const
```

Answer (score 1):

As written the Bar object will be passed by value. You can always define another function if you need it by reference

Ex.

```
template<typename T> void fooByRef(const T& a) { ... }
```